# Mysql, In Update statement where condition have Primary key column and Non-indexed column So Is it table level locking or row level locking?

Tags: mysql, sql, locking, database-deadlocks

I am continuously getting deadlock error regarding one update query. Both transactions are showing same update statement that is mentioned below

Table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `questionname` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    ctype VARCHAR(20),
    `isActive` TINYINT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=525672
;
```

Update statement

```
UPDATE question SET isActive=1 WHERE id=5 and CType='CTEE';
```

In my code snippet `id` is primary key and remaining columns are not consider as unique, Both primary key column and non-indexed columns are applied in where clause.
So I planned to remove the column Ctype (non-indexed column) from where clause.

My questions are:

1. Currently where clause condition have primary key column and non unique key. Is it table or row level level locking?
2. If I am removing Ctype condition from where clause. Is it good solution?

Comment: You shouldn't get the deadlock because of running this statement in 2 transactions, but because of the statements before this update that are in the same transaction (did you maybe run a select to find unactive rows without using the id-column?). While the answer to your 2 questions might be of some general interest ([innodb doesn't use table locks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166242)), they will have almost nothing to do with solving your deadlock problem, so if that is your actual question, you would need to provide more context about your deadlock (rest of your code, innodb status).

Comment: @Solarflare Thank you for your response, you are correct . My actual question is if we add more where condition (All are in AND operation) with primary key condition  so it could be row or table level locking?.

Comment: I heard if we use Primary key or Uniquekey column in where clause it could be row level locking but remaining cases are table level locking

Comment: In this case combination of Primary key and Non primary condition with AND operator so which locking type is applied for this case?

Comment: As explained in the linked answer, innodb doesn't use table locking.